# Can't animate bones

Tags: animation

I have bought a number of models from the Synty store and imported in to blender but I can't seem to animate them.  All of the models already include bones and I can use to reposition the model but when I try to create more than one keyframes all of my keyframes end up with the same rotation data.

Does anyone know what I need to do to animate the models?

[image: Image of the model I'm trying to animate]

Comment: On your screen is not any key frame set. If you already tried import model into a new blend file and issue persist than upload simple file with armature via https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com so we can check. BTW are you able to animate single bone added into a new file?

Comment: I've actually been able to get it to animate by selecting an individual bone and pressing 'i' over the rotation in the transform panel.  Before I was adjusting the model pressing 'a' to select all the bones and then pressing 'i' over the dopesheet or timeline and then selecting 'add all channels'.  My current process is a lot slower than the one I've used before and I'm not really sure if there is a quick way to add all the bones to the dope sheet.

Comment: It should work select all (A) and keyframe (I) all as well. You just need to work like that for each keyframe. As I wrote - would be better post a simplified file with issue and should what it does and what it should do on two keyframes. Like now its hard to say and it will be time consuming to continue in conversation like this. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anybody will be looking for the answer in the future:

1. Make sure you selected Pose Position in your Armature Object Data properties.
2. Your bones don't have active constraints. (deactivate all the constraints to make sure they don't affect animations)
3. Graph Editor should display your keyframes
4. Nonlinear Animation editor doesn't have any active tracks (all stars should be dark and checkboxes empty). In the screenshot below the problem was caused by the nonlinear animation editor [image: can't animate the bones]